# Delayed actions and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, timer, broadcastreceiver, timertask

I have a case in which I have to start some non-UI action **N seconds after** power has been connected to the device. That action could be also started by user via UI.

I have a BroadcastReceiver defined in **AndroidManifest.xml** which listens for **ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED**.

I have a service that does required action on **onStartCommand**. My question is - what is the right way to start that service in case of when action is triggered by broadcast?

I have two options in mind:

1. One-shot timer task. However I think it might be wrong because of according to docs, I could't start any async tasks from BroadcastReceiver.
2. Redesign service:

   - start action at **onStartCommand**, if action was triggered by user
   - start timer task and do action at timer shot - same logic as in 1. but inside service - if action was triggered by broadcast.

I am inclined to 2. It will make code a bit more complex, but it seems it is only right way.

-Lev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is #2. That's because as soon as you leave `onReceive` application process might be killed. And your `TimerTask` won't help in such case.

As an alternative solution, use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and its [`set`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) function to schedule pending service intent. This is probably the best solution in your case.